# Decryption error: caused by java.lang.noclassdeffounderror com/android/org/constcrypt/OpenSSLRSAPublicKey android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, android-6.0-marshmallow

Hi I am trying to decrypt the stuff from my public key on Android:

```
public String decrypt(String basetext) {

        try {
            FileInputStream iR = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/publickkey");
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(iR);
            final PublicKey key = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();

            byte[] text = Base64.decode(basetext, Base64.DEFAULT);

            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

            // decrypt the text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

            iR.close();
            return new String(dectyptedText,"UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        }
    }
```

It works fine on my marshmallow, tried to run on emulator 4.2.2 and it throws below error:

```
caused by java.lang.noclassdeffounderror com/android/org/constcrypt/OpenSSLRSAPublicKey android
```

If I see my imports there is no imports like above error

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
```

This works fine on real device android marshmallow,4.2.2 on emulator it crashes

full class :-

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class EncryptionUtils {

    public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    public static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "/sdcard/private.key";
    public static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "/sdcard/public.key";

    public static void generateKey() {
        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            keyGen.initialize(2048);
            final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

            File privateKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
            File publicKeyFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

            // Create files to store public and private key
            if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

            if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

            // Saving the Public key in a file
            ObjectOutputStream publicKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile));
            publicKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPublic());
            publicKeyOS.close();

            // Saving the Private key in a file
            ObjectOutputStream privateKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile));
            privateKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPrivate());
            privateKeyOS.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String encrypt(String text, PrivateKey key) {
        try {
            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            // encrypt the plain text using the private key
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return  base64;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String basetext, PublicKey key) {

        try {
            byte[] text = Base64.decode(basetext, Base64.DEFAULT);

            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

            // decrypt the text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);
            return new String(dectyptedText,"UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the only thing is that real cryptography is added in android 4.3 and up,so on android 4.2 and below it will cause problem because openssl class was made default in api 18,so using this rsa encrypting/decryption is fine on 4.3+ else to support below use some other techniques.

thats whay is the solution from my side,if anybody else get this porblem you can see the solution here,

or if someone managed to make it work without using third party libraries then he is most welcome to write it here

Answer (score 0):

It pays to be **specific** when defining the cipher you intend to use.  Instead of using:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

You should try:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

I believe there were some inconsistencies between plain Java and Android, I don't recall what versions, but in most cases the adjustment above fixes the problem.

Comment: still force close

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ObjectOutputStream` / `ObjectInputStream` to store the keys. The underlying implementation class of `PublicKey` vary between versions and the serialization of an object using an internal class will fail if the class it is not present in a upper version.

I suggest to store the public key data directly

```
byte publicKeyData[] = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

And load it using

```
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyData);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec);
```

Note also that in android previous to `4.3` the cryptographic provider is not fully implemented and non conventional operations like decryption with RSA public key and encryption with private key can be used with guarantees.

### UPDATED - Spongycastle

Alternatively you can use spongycastle cryptographic provider to generate and load the keys

**Gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.51.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.51.0.0'
```

**Adding the provider**

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

**USAGE**

Add `SC` to the provider parameter. For example

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen= KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
```

See more info [here](http://blog.brainattica.com/working-with-rsa-in-android-3/)

Comment: well it wont have any issues either,the main problem is that RSA won't work perfectly below android 4.3 thats why it is getting force close.so need to work out something for below android 4.3

Comment: I checked with <4.3 that encryption with private key from System key store does not work, but I do not know if affects to a generated key pair.  Just test it. If it does not work, I figure you can use other cryptographic provider like spongycastle. In any case, really you need encryption with private key? This does not add privacity because anyone with public key can decrypt. If you are looking for digital signatures, android has a perfectly working implementation

Comment: yes on 4.3 and up it works fine,but below it will result in crash,you can read most of the stuff is added in api 18 for cryptography https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html,,well can you give me the link of android implementation ?

Comment: Yes,  I know the advantages since android 18 and the native implementation of a security keystore. I have posted some examples using Spongycastle provider.

Comment: spongycastle can solve the problem but increases size in MBs which is downgrade,so i thought to use rsa on 4.3 and up else use something else